# Arg list no being iterated over

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I am trying to iterate over a list of links.

```
#!/bin/bash

 function cloneAll {
   echo $(pwd)
   for i in "${@}"
   do
           echo "works"
           echo "$i"
   done
 }

 cloneAll
```

I call this as `./clone_list link1 link2`

I actually want to do a git clone on these links, but it is not even going into the for loop, so I thought I could get the echo within the loop to work first.

It does not give any error. The `echo $(pwd)` outside the loop works. So I know the script executes.

What am I missing here?

Edit:

I dont know if it makes a difference, but I've also tried

`for i in "$@"`

Comment: You are not passing the arguments to cloneAll - you need `cloneAll "$@"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an extra ${@} at the end worked on my system.

```
#!/bin/bash

 function cloneAll {
   echo $(pwd)
   for i in "${@}"
   do
           echo "works"
           echo "$i"
   done
 }

 cloneAll "${@}"
```

Comment: Quote the `${@}`